# Why does Jenkins fail to build Play project due to "routes is already defined as object routes"?

Tags: playframework-2.0, sbt, typesafe-activator

I have a Play project that builds fine on my MacBook, but fails on a remote build server running Jenkins on Ubuntu Server 14. The build fails with the following error:

```
[info] Compiling 7 Scala sources and 120 Java sources to /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/<redacted-projectname>/workspace/target/scala-2.11/classes...
[error] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/<redacted-projectname>/workspace/conf/routes: routes is already defined as object routes
[error] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/<redacted-projectname>/workspace/conf/routes: routes is already defined as class routes
[error] two errors found
```

The same problem appears on my local machine as well at times, but I just have to do a `./activator clean` (or `sbt clean`) and then it works fine.

The Jenkins build profile is an `Execute Shell` directive that executes the following script:

```
./activator clean dist
```

I have tried recreating the project, completely cleaned the directory, but the builds continue to fail. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you try `./activator clean dist`? I'm pretty sure that Jenkins could clean up the workspace itself, so `clean` is not really required. Can you check if you have `target` directory committed to the repo? You should not.

Comment: Sorry for the extremely late reply. I tried ./activator clean dist, it isn't working. And no, the `target` directory was by default in the `.gitignore` and is not under version control.

Comment: When you say *"it isn't working"*, would you mind pasting the output? https://gist.github.com would be fine.

Comment: Absolutely. Here it is: https://gist.github.com/RohanPrabhuNomadly/1e977db4def6ae458a5b

Comment: I must add that, I am able to build this perfectly on my MacBook, but on the remote build server (running Ubuntu Server 14) it fails.

Comment: Can you execute `./activator compile` as a Jenkins job? [Lines 490-491](https://gist.github.com/RohanPrabhuNomadly/1e977db4def6ae458a5b#file-gistfile1-txt-L490-L491) seem fishy. Can you see what's inside the auto-generated `target/scala-2.11/src_managed/main/controllers/routes.java`? The public class `routes` should be inside the package `controllers`. Can you include it in the gist?

Comment: This is the output of `./activator compile` as a Jenkins task: https://gist.github.com/RohanPrabhuNomadly/c3f1273e255c8c9309b4 . This is routes.java: https://gist.github.com/RohanPrabhuNomadly/97b5b139839b46d82840

Comment: Btw, till we are trying to figure it out, I would like you to know that I am immensely grateful for all your help. Thank you so much for your time :)

Comment: Can you go to the Jenkins machine and run the command `./activator compile` by yourself? Can you execute `./activator about` and paste the output along with `cat project/plugins.sbt`? I'm getting lost what might be wrong here :(

Comment: Could it be that the issue is https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/3523 and the solution is *don't put your router in a package that has controllers in it.*? Worth checking out anyway.

Comment: So, there has been a recent development (could be that I missed it the first time). `./activator clean compile` is now working fine, but `./activator dist` is failing. I ran the same via SSHing into the build box and got the same results. At the same time, here is the output you asked for: https://gist.github.com/RohanPrabhuNomadly/d1c8f78126ef55d1d959

Comment: One thing I've noticed is that the document generation is failing. This is the output when I ran it via SSH in the build box: `[error] (compile:doc) Scaladoc generation failed`. Is this task only a dependency for `dist` and not `compile`? And I checked out the issue you linked to and it doesn't apply to me (I don't have any routes in a package with controllers).

Comment: I just tried doing a search with `find` for all files called `routes` and I found quite a bit of stuff: https://gist.github.com/RohanPrabhuNomadly/6ea107b8a392e983f1e5

Comment: While we are talking about really interesting and weird stuff, the `dist` task is working on jenkins after I added this line to *build.sbt*: `sources in (Compile,doc) := Seq.empty`